# Keep a round divided new column

Tags: r

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), num = c(123, 23, 3210))
```

How is it possible to divide with 30 the column num and round it to the highest value and create a new column in the dataframe

example output

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), num = c(123, 43, 3210), round = c(5, 1, 107))
```

Comment: subtract with 30 and round it?

Comment: Try: `x$round <- ceiling(x$num / 30)`

Comment: do you mean divide instead of subtract instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ceiling`:

```
x$round <- ceiling(x$num / 30)
x
#  id  num round
#1  1  123     5
#2  2   23     1
#3  3 3210   107
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(round = ceiling(num/30))
  id  num round
1  1  123     5
2  2   23     1
3  3 3210   107
```